# How do I render a single tweet in a webpage?

Tags: jquery, twitter

I am trying to include a rendered tweet in a webpage. I searched around and eventually got myself this solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.jsonid=287348974577385474&align=center&callback=?",
        function(data{$('#tweet123').html(data.html);});
});
</script>


<div id="tweet123"></div>
```

Now, this is only giving me the tweet text. I want the nicely rendered tweet, like the one I see here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets

I think I should mention that I have jquery somewhere else on the page I want to make. I suppose I could remove it if I need to do that in order to get rendering working. But I'd rather not.

**edit:** the page looks like this, I am not happy with the rendering:
[image: not rendered the way I want]

**edit:** my code right now, bear with me I know almost nothing about web programming:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../supporting_data/seaofclouds-tweet-d433d14/tweet/jquery.tweet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA4aH3NUbCC-DiqD1hUcsy6EMPmqDgn-Yo&sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id=287348974577385474&align=center&callback=?,
        function(data{$('#tweet123').html(data.html);});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>



<p>
<div id='tweet123'></div>  
</p>


<!-- experiment with seaofclouds -->
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery(function($){
                $(".coffeeTweet").tweet({
                    username: "coffee_dad",
                    join_text: "auto",
                    avatar_size: 32,
                    count: 5,
                    loading_text: "downloading tweets..."
                });
            });
        </script>
<p>
<div class="coffeeTweet"></div>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us a copy of the rendered HTML that appears in div #tweet123?

Comment: My mistake, I was meaning the actual HTML code if possible. Also is there any reason your script tag src does not include the http part?

Comment: I posted what I'm doing. I really don't understand web programming at all, so the src/http inclusions/exclusions are something I can't explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can try changing `//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js` to `http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js`

**EDIT:**

The following works from my computer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id=287348974577385474&align=center&callback=?",
        function(data){$('#tweet123').html(data.html);});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>



<div id='tweet123'></div>  



</body>
</html>
```

[image: HTML Output]

**EDIT:**
I am running this web page from a local web server on my computer. I get the same result as you if I simply open the file in my browser with the `file:///` protocol.

I would try running the file on a web server, because very often your browser will restrict certain operations while under the `file:///` protocol for security reasons.

Comment: is the page live somewhere?

Comment: Huh, well, I have no idea what is going on. It still won't render for me. I will give this a try from my apartment, my work has a "websense" filter that sometimes blocks stuff.

Comment: Hey what computer are you using? I can't get it to render on any of the 3 I've tried.

Comment: Sony Vaio running apache 2.2 web server. Are you just opening it as a local file?

Comment: ya, just opened up the local file. Could that do something wrong?

Comment: Yeah, sometimes certain things are restricted under the file:/// protocol for security. I updated my Answer. The good news is that it should be fine once the page is on a server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you'd also need to include the associated css that styles this markup from twitter.

Comment: @joeltine I think the css is retrieved by the included widget.js script so there are no other resources available from twitter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the fully rendered tweet, you're going to have to embed it using the methods found  here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-tweets

Comment: yes, that link was in the question I posted. But I can't seem to find what I'm missing there.